# Cleaning django RESTful input causes routing error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to validate a MAC address in my API and re-format it to a consistent internal representation.

The following code correctly populates the table, but django then throws an error when trying to create the view for that table.

It complains that "nic-detail" is not found. I'm guessing what's happening is that the url gets updated with the passed-in value to the validation function and NOT with the updated value. Is there a different way?

```
class NICSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def validate_mac(self, value):
        regex = re.compile(r'^([0-9a-f]{2}([-:\.]?)[0-9a-f]{2}(\2[0-9a-f]{2}){4})$')

        m = regex.match(value)

        if not m:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not a valid mac address")
        return value

        sep = m.groups()[1]
        if sep != '':
            return m.groups[0].replace(sep,'.')
        else:
            return '.'.join([m.groups()[0][x:x+2] for x in range(0,len(m.groups()[0]),2)])

    class Meta:
        model = models.NIC
        fields = ('url', 'mac', 'system')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been awhile since I asked this question, but I ended up with a solution that seems to work well:

Create a MACField serializer field:

```
class MACField(serializers.Field):

    def validate(self, value):
        regex = re.compile(
            r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}([:\-.])[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(\2[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){4})$'
        )
        m = regex.match(value)

        if not m:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Not a valid mac address.'
            )
        return m.groups()[1]

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        delimiter = self.validate(data)
        return ':'.join(data.lower().split(delimiter))
```

Then simply use this in the serializer class:

```
class NICSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    mac = MACField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.NIC
        fields = ('url', 'mac', 'system')
```

Now if someone enters an invalid MAC a `ValidationError` is raised, and if it is valid then the `validate` function returns the delimiting character of the MAC. The internal representation is then the colon-delimited version.

Answer (score 0):

Does your view have a `queryset` field?  If not, you need to specify the `base_name` parameter when you register your view with the DRF router in `urls.py`.  [See `rest_framework.routers` usage](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage)

Comment: It does have a queryset. Everything works if I simply pass back 'values' rather than reformatting it.

Comment: Did you try specifying the `base_name` parameter?

Comment: I don't believe that's the issue. Or if it is could you be more specific? Here's what I'm asking:
add mac "de:ad:ca:fe:ba:be" to database. If I simply verify and return this string the view works fine. However, if I return "de.ad.ca.fe.ba.be" from the validation function it complains about "nic-detail". This leads me to believe it's looking for the ":" delimited string instead of the "." delimited string.

Comment: The string "`nic-detail`" pertains to doing a reverse URL lookup.  Some chunk of code has a Django model instance and it needs to find its URL.  In Django, there is a map that maps a model's canonical detail name ("`nic-detail`") to the URL.  In your case, when it does the lookup it can't find any URL in its router for "`nic-detail`".    In your `urls.py` file where you are calling `router.register(r'nic', views.NicViewSet)` just try adding the `base_name` parameter like `router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet, base_name="nic-detail")` and see what happens.

Comment: Tried for grins, didn't work, same error message. The reason I didn't think it would is because it _does_ work _without_ the validate function.

Comment: Ahh.       Apologies.  Got an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the whole enchilada?